# In how many ways can $12$ people be seated in a row of $16$ seats so that there are at least two consecutive empty seats?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $12$ people be seated in a series of $16$ consecutive theater seats, in such a way that there are always at least $2$ consecutive empty seats?

Sorry but I am not familiar with combinatorics!

Comment: We can do this by subtracting the number of seating arrangements with fewer than two consecutive empty seats from the total.  Since there are only $12$ people, there must be four empty seats.  Therefore, we wish to subtract the number of seating arrangements in which the four empty seats are separated from the total number of seating arrangements.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have attempted and indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Notice, that there would be 4 empty seats.

We can split them into (oreder of groups of different sizes does matter):

- 1 group of 4 (1 way)
- 2 groups of 2 (1 way)
- 1 group of 1 and 1 group of 3 (2 ways)
- 2 groups of 1 and 1 group of 2 (3 ways)

Thus there is one way of splitting into 1 group, 3 ways of splitting into 2 groups and 3 ways of splitting into 3 groups.

Now for each number $k$ of grups we can find number of splitting 12 people with these groups $s_k = \binom{12+1}{k}$
$$s_1=\binom{13}{1}=13\\s_2=\binom{13}{2}=78 \\ s_3 = \binom{13}{3}=286$$

Of course 12 people can be ordered in $12!$ ways. So the final answer is:

$$X=12!\left(\binom{13}{1}+3\binom{13}{2}+3\binom{13}{3}\right)$$

Comment: Yes but 12 people in 16 seats can be seated in 16!/(16-12)! different ways, right?

Comment: @Alex.vollenga  This answer is correct.  First, the empty seats are selected, then the people are placed in the remaining seats.  I outlined an alternative method in the comments which you can use to check the answer.